# Path of newly captured image by camera always return empty

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm building an app and one of its features is take picture and upload it to server.

Here's how I do it. I use `reqCode = 7`

```
btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, reqCode);
    }
});

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), requestCode + " - " + resultCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if(requestCode == reqCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageCamera.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), bitmap);

        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Here "+ tempUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed To Capture Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private Uri getImageUri(Context applicationContext, Bitmap photo) {
    Bitmap OutImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, 1000, 1000,true);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(applicationContext.getContentResolver(), OutImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

The weird thing is, String path in getImageUri always return empty. What is the right way to get image path of recently captured picture by camera? And what is the right request code for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
File file;
Uri fileUri;

    final int RC_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

        private void takePhoto() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            file = new File(getActivity().getExternalCacheDir(), 
                    String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
            fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
            getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, RC_TAKE_PHOTO);

        }


        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == RC_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    //do whatever you need with taken photo using file or fileUri

                    galleryUpdatePic(tmpFileUri.getPath());

                        Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(tmpFileUri.getPath())
                    .into(img_profile_user);

                }
            }
        }




    private void galleryUpdatePic(String mediaUrl) {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(mediaUrl);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }
```